# App is sending mm/dd/yyyy but SQL Server is expecting dd/mm/yyyy issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm working on an old .NET 2.0 site that's having an issue with date searches.

After a few hours of troubleshooting I've come to the conclusion that the search parameters being sent are in a `MM/DD/YYYY` format and SQL Server is expecting `DD/MM/YYYY`

I'm not sure how to fix this.

I've tried converting it to string with ( `.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` ) then back to `DateTime`. This isn't working because it needs to be a nullable `DateTime`

> CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'TableAdapters.Artist_ListTableAdapter.GetData(int, System.DateTime?,
>   System.DateTime?, int?, int?, bool?, string, string, string, int?,
>   int?, int?, int?, int?, out int?)' has some invalid arguments

Now I don't understand much about SQL Server stored procedures so I have no idea how to look at that `GetData` function... when I right click and go to definition I get a generated c# page.

Any help?

EDIT: @BigM Not sure if this will help but:

Var declaration:

```
public DataTable dtArtist = new DataTable();
public string cp_basePath;
public int pagecount;
int CultureId ;
DateTime? startDate;
DateTime? endDate;
int? disciplineId = null;
int? minimumGradelevel = null;
int? maximumGradelevel = null;
int? languageId = null;
bool? isFeatured = null;
int? educationalInitiativeId = null;
string EducationalInitiativeIds = string.Empty;
string sortColumnName = string.Empty;
string searchCriteria = string.Empty;
```

Grabbed from query string:

```
private void GetQueryStrings()
{
    CultureId = objGeneralLayer.plCultureId;
    if (Request.QueryString["StartDate"] != null)
        startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.QueryString["StartDate"].ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    if (Request.QueryString["EndDate"] != null)
        endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.QueryString["EndDate"].ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    if (Request.QueryString["DisciplineId"] != null)
        disciplineId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["DisciplineId"].ToString());
    if (Request.QueryString["MinGrade"] != null)
        minimumGradelevel = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["MinGrade"].ToString());
    if (Request.QueryString["MaxGrade"] != null)
        maximumGradelevel = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["MaxGrade"].ToString());
    if (Request.QueryString["LanguageId"] != null)
        languageId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["LanguageId"].ToString());
    if (Request.QueryString["Featured"] != null)
        isFeatured = Convert.ToBoolean(Request.QueryString["Featured"].ToString());
    if (Request.QueryString["EducatIds"] != null)
        EducationalInitiativeIds = Request.QueryString["EducatIds"].ToString();
    if (Request.QueryString["Criteria"] != null)
        searchCriteria = Request.QueryString["Criteria"].ToString();
}
```

Then later on in the code:

```
dtArtist = objArtistLayer.getArtistList(CultureId,startDate, endDate, disciplineId, languageId, minimumGradelevel, maximumGradelevel, isFeatured, sortColumnName, searchCriteria, EducationalInitiativeIds, Stakeholder, currPage, pageSize, out rowCount);
```

Then later on:

```
public DataTable getArtistList( int CultureId ,
                                DateTime? StartDate
                                ,DateTime? EndDate
                                ,int? DisciplineId
                                ,int? LanguageId
                                ,int? MinimumGradeLevel
                                ,int? MaximumGradeLevel
                                ,bool? IsFeature
                                ,string ColumnName
                                ,string Criteria
                                ,string EducationalInitiativeIds
                                ,int ? StakeholderId
                                ,int StartPage   
                                ,int PageSize   
                                ,out int RowCount   
                                )
{
    int? count = 0;
    StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    TableAdapters.Artist_ListTableAdapter ada = new TableAdapters.Artist_ListTableAdapter();
    dt = ada.GetData(CultureId
                    , StartDate
                    , EndDate
                    , MinimumGradeLevel
                    , MaximumGradeLevel
                    , IsFeature
                    , ColumnName
                    , Criteria
                    , EducationalInitiativeIds
                    , StakeholderId
                    , DisciplineId
                    , LanguageId
                    , StartPage
                    , PageSize
                    , out count
                    );
    RowCount = (int)count;
    return dt;
```

Comment: Please share all of the code that relates to loading the data, including the lines that prepare everything.

Comment: The error that you posted doesn't sound like it has anything to do with SQL. The method GetData is expecting a parameter that is either missing or a parameter that you're supplying is of the wrong type.

Comment: System.DateTime?, System.DateTime? are nulluable datetimes is any of those get passed as null?

Comment: @marc_s yes SQL server sorry.

Comment: Do you have the right value in startDate? I think it might be a problem from converting string to date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DateTime` doesn't have a format - it's just a date/time value.  Converting it to a string then converting it back to a date is useless - you're going to get the same value back.

Your issue is more likely when you're converting the `QueryString` parameters from strings to dates. This is the only place in the code you've posted that represents dates as strings.  You need to have some way to enforce a particular format, otherwise `Convert.ToDateTime` going to try and *infer* the format, which could be wrong when the month and day are ambiguous.  e.g. is 2/3/2013 Feb 3rd or Mar 2nd?

If your query string variable is ALWAYS in the format `mm/dd/yyyy` then use `ParseExact` to convert it to a `DateTime`:

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

if (Request.QueryString["StartDate"] != null)
    startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Request.QueryString["StartDate"], "MM/dd/yyyy", provider);
if (Request.QueryString["EndDate"] != null)
    endDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Request.QueryString["EndDate"], "MM/dd/yyyy", provider);
```

Comment: This is likely your problem. It sounds like the date in the query string is in the wrong format. Fix that and your problem will be fixed.

Comment: I think this is my problem... the query string is in mm/dd/yyyy and c# wants dd/mm/yyyy and SQL wants mm/dd/yyyy. I need to figure out how to get c# to not mix the days and months up

Comment: Unless there's something you're note posting, SQL is getting date values, not strings, so it's not expecting any "format".  If the query string is ALWAYS in "mm/dd/yyyy" then use `ParseExact()`.  I'll add an example.

Comment: This is definately my issue... an example would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your exception said that signature of your method should be:

```
TableAdapters.Artist_ListTableAdapter.GetData(int, System.DateTime?, System.DateTime?, int?, int?, bool?, string, string, string, int?, int?, int?, int?, int?, out int?)
```

But you call it as:

```
ada.GetData(CultureId,
                    ArtistId
                    , StakeholderId
                    , StartDate
                    , EndDate
                    , DisciplineId
                    , MinimumGradeLevel
                    , MaximumGradeLevel
                    , LanguageId
                    , IsFeature
                    , ShowId
                    );
```

You can see that there exists a mismatching in parameters - in exception it said that DateTime parameters should be 2nd and 3 rd. But you call it as 4th and 5th.

Comment: The issue I'm having is I can't find a good spot to convert it without crashing it. It's expecting a nullable datetime so I can't convert it within the c# code.

Comment: By the way you are post StartDate and EndDate to GetDate method as 4-th and 5-th parameters, but your exception said than "TableAdapters.Artist_ListTableAdapter.GetData(int, System.DateTime?, System.DateTime?" it should be 2nd and 3rd parameters. Is it an issue?

Comment: you can't "convert it" once it is a datetime... going back to string then back to datetime don't do anything. see above, you are probably setting it wrong to begin with.

Comment: FYI... I edited my post. I had originally posted the wrong function. Which lead to the call it as issue you pointed at.